# Bash : Concatenate variables containing strings n columns by n columns

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

I have 2 variables containing the same number of information, here 1 line with n=3 columns (I mean separated by a space)

```
var1='abc def ghi'
var2='klm nop qrs'
```

I would like the output to be the concatenated result with one line and 3 columns, with the following pattern :

```
abcklm defnop ghiqrs
```

I tried with a `$(paste <echo $var1) <(echo $var2) -d  '')`
But it does the same as `$var1$var2`.

The `pr -ms' ' $var1 $var2` doesn't work, it's like it is waiting for a file rather than a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste -d "" <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var1") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var2") | paste -sd " "
```

- convert the space-separated variables into newline-separated files.
- join the files.
- then join the output lines.

Documentation:

- [3.5.6 Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)
- [3.6.7 Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)
- man pages for `tr` and `paste`

Comment: Thanks it does exactly what I want, but can you give more details for it ? So I can understand it properly